# How to download a file uploaded on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am currently facing a problem with the google cloud storage,

I was able to download objects uploaded on the google cloud storage, but later part of the day, I started getting the error as "This site cannot be reached"

I created a bucket programmatically in c#, the code is as follows:

```
public void CreateBucket(string bucketName, string projectid)
        {
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            storage.CreateBucket(projectid, bucketName);
        }
```

So the bucket was created with the settings as follows:

Default Storage Class: multi regional

Location: us (multiple regions in United States)

Public access: Per object

Lifecycle: None

Access control model: Bucket policy & ACLs

I was able to download the objects in the bucket by clicking on the name of the object and it would download.
But now when I try clicking on the name of the file, I get a message as follows:

This site can’t be reached The webpage at https://storage.cloud.google.com//?_ga=XXXXXXXB might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

 I am using google chrome to access google cloud storage website

I also tried right click on the file name and Save As, but both gives the same browser error message.

**Update**

[image: Bucket List]

Bucket is created using the code mentioned above

[image: File List in the Bucket]

Uploaded the test.txt file by drag drop and the file is displayed in the list

[image: Error]

Click on the file to download and the error appears



Please note the bucket name and project id are marked in black in the image.

Comment: It may have been deleted or moved somewhere else via gsutil or client library/API. If you click the 'Refresh bucket' in the UI, can you still see the file?

Comment: In order to get more information, could you please share a screenshot of the error and the process flow that you are following to perform your actions?

Comment: @Christopher: Yes the files are present even after refreshing the bucket, in fact I deleted the file and upload a new text file, just incase to check its not because of cache

Comment: @AndieVega: I have uploaded the images to explain the workflow and issue

Comment: @JPais, in such case, you should be filing an issue here --> https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: It maybe a UI or IAM issue, try also downloading the file by using gsutil command: gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCATION]

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects

Comment: @Christopher: the service account is set to Storage admin and the logged in user that is my id is set to owner, is it right?
Also the gsutil download command didn't respond anything

Comment: if you see in the second image where the file list is displayed, the "Public access" column has the value "Not public". does that mean something

Comment: Open an issue here so this can be investigated  https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. This is more like a billing related (possibly billing account closed, etc.), UI (since you can't download the same using gsutil then this is less likely a UI issue), or IAM issue.

Comment: Opened an issue regarding this

Comment: @JPais  Could you please share the answer once that someone answer you? In order to know the solution of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make public access for text.txt. On your screenshot, it wasn't public.

[image]